# Is this right way to fadein and fadeout an UIView?

Tags: ios, uiviewanimation

This fades in and fade the UIView by pressing an button, but seems that this code can be written better:

```
- (IBAction)navigationTap:(id)sender {
if (navigationFolded == TRUE) {
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"MoveOut" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.2f];
    self.moveMe.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, _moveMe.bounds.size.width, _moveMe.bounds.size.height);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    navigationFolded = FALSE;
} else {
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"MoveIn" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.2f];
    self.moveMe.frame = CGRectMake(50-_moveMe.bounds.size.width, 0, _moveMe.bounds.size.width, _moveMe.bounds.size.height);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    navigationFolded = TRUE;
}
```

Comment: I suppose "fade in/out" should mean changing view transparency, not frame? Also you should use newer block-based animation methods from UIView

Comment: the uiview fades in from the left side of the display...
What do you mean with "newer block based animation"?

Comment: if it from the left, then it "slides in"?  Anyway I am not native english speaker, I may be wrong. Check [UIView animateWithDuration:...] method and similar

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code it sounds like you want the `UIView` to slide in from the side of the screen. Fading would involve animating the `alpha` value of the `UIView`

Your code can be simplified by using the newer block based syntax for doing animations and by only wrapping just the value of the x position in an if statement since it's the only part that changes with `navigationFolded`.

```
- (IBAction)navigationTap:(id)sender {
    NSInteger xPos = 0;
    if (!navigationFolded) {
        xPos = 50-_moveMe.bounds.size.width
    }

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2f delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{
        self.moveMe.frame = CGRectMake(xPos, 0, _moveMe.bounds.size.width, _moveMe.bounds.size.height);
    } completion:nil];

    navigationFolded = !navigationFolded;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
- (IBAction)navigationTap:(id)sender {
if (navigationFolded == TRUE) {
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"MoveOut" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.2f];
    self.moveMe.alpha = 1;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    navigationFolded = FALSE;
} else {
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"MoveIn" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.2f];
    self.moveMe.alpha = 0;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    navigationFolded = TRUE;
}
```

(I may have the cases mixed up - in this case the IF statement should make the UIView visible, and the else will make it fade out gradually. YMMV).